# Using JavaScript to switch through tabs without changing layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My webpage is at http://sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html

I have done all the layout and coding. I want the tabs to toggle when clicked over them. I tried google but was in vain. I am willing to achieve the effect using either JavaScript or jQuery. My tabs are empty right now,  And I want the layout to remain the same.

NEW :

This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lis = $('#main-tabs li');
  lis.click( function() {
  //Reset all the tabs
  lis.removeClass('active-tab').addClass('inactive-tab');
  $(this).addClass('active-tab');
   });

 </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".tab-content").hide();
 $("ul#main-tabs li a:first").addClass("active").show();
 $("#wrap > div").hide().filter(":first").show();

 $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li > a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#wrap > div").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
  });

});

</script>
```

For the full HTML and JavaSript code (new) please go to  http://sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html

What it does is that when I click on a list item, it changes the tab, but not the content. And when I click on the anchor of a list item, it changes the content, but not the tab. I want both the content and the tab to change consistently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI is probably the best solution. You can use the [.tabs()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
 to accomplish what you are trying to do. You can also edit the layout easily by using [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Comment: the thing is that I am not very familiar with jQuery. If you can please assist me with the process I shall be very grateful. :)

Comment: You will need to download jQuery and jQuery UI.

jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/download

Then follow this tutorial for installing / configuring jQuery UI. 
http://drupal.org/node/1078080

Comment: jQuery UI is the better option over plain javascript - no need to reinvent the wheel. If you follow the link to tabs that Farhan provided in his answer, there is more than enough information to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

This quick test is working pretty well

```
var lis = $('#main-tabs li');
lis.click( function() {
  //Reset all the tabs
  lis.removeClass('active-tab').addClass('inactive-tab');
  $(this).addClass('active-tab');
});
```

Of course it doesn't consider the content of the tabs, but it's a start :)

Comment: this is great.. now when I have content on the tabs too, what else should I add to the script?